# Definite integrals involving $\sin^{n}{(x)}$ for n even and odd

Tags: definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

Looking for expressions for the following 4 definite integrals (since for both odd and even $n$) (and only care about $n>0$):

$\int_{0}^{\pi}{\sin^{n}{(x)}dx}$

and

$\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\sin^{n}{(x)}dx}$.

---

For the latter, I know I get a fraction which is:

$\pi(OEIS A001790) / (OEIS A120777)$

---

Also, I know I should be able to use the recurrence:

$$\int{\sin^{n}{(x)}\,dx} = -\frac{\sin^{n-1}(x)\cos(x)}{n} + \frac{n-1}{n}\int{\sin^{n-2}{(x)}\,dx}$$

from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_integrals#Trigonometric_functions
but when I multiply it out the n-1 / n fraction has the wrong power.

Comment: What is OEIS&c.?

Comment: @Bernard [OEIS](https://oeis.org/): The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences.

Answer (score 0):

**Sketch:**

This is the same recurrence relation as the the *Wallis' integrals* (for which the bounds are $0$ and $\pi/2$). Denoting $I_n$ one of these integrals (bounds $0$ and $\pi$ or $2\pi$), you obtain the relation
$$I_n=\frac{n-1}n \,I_{n-2},$$
whence:

- if $n=2m$, $\enspace I_n=\dfrac{(2m-1)(2m-3)\dotsm 1}{2m(2m-2)\dotsm2}I_0=\dfrac{(2m)!}{\bigl(2m(2m-2)\dotsm2\bigr)^2}I_0=\dfrac{(2m)!}{2^{2m}(m!)^2}I_0$;
- if $n=2m+1$,$\enspace I_n=\dfrac{2m(2m-2)\dotsm\dotsm2}{(2m+1)(2m-1)\dotsm 3}I_1=\dfrac{2^{2m}(m!)^2}{(2m+1)!}I_1$